# SMD Elements on the back of THT

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount, pins

I'm designing a PCB right now and found out I can save a lot of space using the back of THT elements:

[image: SMD elements on the back of THT]

In the picture there's IC1 (ATMega) and LCD. I design only 1-sided PCB for now. IC1 and LCD are put "flipped", so the pins of them are on this side, and the big things (screen, IC1 main body) on the back (easier to solder).

My PCB has limited size and because of that I though of maybe of using the area between pins of IC1 and the whole empty area of the back of LCD. It's a lot of space to use and as you can see with C2 example - easier and shorter.
I know that maybe for ADC elements the problem may happen, because of same GND grid or something like that, but it's not the problem in this situation.

Is is legit to design like that? Are there any problems that might occur? Any opinion appreciated.

Comment: For manual assembly it's fine. For automated manufacture you have to glue the component down so it doesn't fall off when you wave solder your through hole parts

Comment: There are several methods of double sided SMD in home built and automation.  Keep in mind pad sizes depend on which process is used. IR reflow, Wave and hand heater over a frying pan to hand solder. The hand soldered parts may use a slightly bigger the pad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can do this**

In general, there is no problem with putting components on both sides of the board, in the same place.  If you had a two (or more) layer board, you's probably want to put a ground or power plane between them, but you can't do that with a single layer board.  So you should watch out for a fast digital chip interfering with an analog circuit.  It would be inadvisable, for example, to put a microcontroller on one side and a high input impedance buffer on the other. But putting decoupling caps opposite the chip is probably a good plan.

If you want to meet CE requirements for noise immunity and emissions, you will have difficulty with this type of design, and a two layer board would help a lot.  For hobby use, what you have looks fine.

Comment: Thank you! I did it and think it'll work because no high-impedance input around :)
Not really a hobby, but enough for a university project.

Answer (score 0):

### This is standard practice

What you are describing is standard practice in much commercial work, using single-sided PCBs and a wave soldering process -- small SMT components are populated and glued to the bottom, larger THT components are shoved in the top, and then the board is run through the wave soldering machine.  In fact, just about any mixed-technology consumer-electronics board that doesn't need to be multilayer will be designed and made that way, even, often with a CEM-1 paper-phenolic substrate instead of glass-epoxy FR-4.

This is also practical with hand-soldering or home-reflow, of course -- populate and solder the SMT parts first, then populate and solder the THT parts.  I've done it myself on a milled single-sided FR-4 board for a test-jig with SMT passives and ICs, but THT connectors and adjustments, as in the layout/assembly drawing below (don't have the actual jig handy any longer to show you pics of the results, sadly):

[image: assembly drawing]